# Finding a specific value in a specific position of an array with MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am fairly new to MongoDB and I am trying to figure out how I can query a collection for a document that contains a *specific value* in a *specific array position*. I have a general idea but I am getting syntax errors when I try to use `$position` so I know I'm off track here despite my best effort with the mongo docs.

As an example document for what I am trying to do, I'll use a recipes database collection:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("1234"),
  "recipeName": "Super tasty cilantro lime chicken",
  "ingredients": ["chicken breast", "cilantro", "lime"]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4321"),
  "recipeName": "Radical Cilantro Dip",
  "ingredients": ["cilantro", "lime", "sour cream"]
}
```

What is the best method for finding only the document(s) that contains cilantro in the 2nd position of the ingredients array instead of all documents containing cilantro in any position?

Comment: Try this  `db.collectionName.find({"ingredients.1": "cilantro"})`

Comment: @RobertMoskal thank you. I can usually find my answer here without posting but I couldn't think of how to word the search properly to get good results.

Comment: @AliDehghani That was so simple THANK YOU. (I was doing it in reverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Ali Dehghani for the answer!

> Try this db.collectionName.find({"ingredients.1": "cilantro"}) – Ali
>   Dehghani